# Spring batch Out of memory after huge select in a job

Tags: java, mysql, spring-batch

I'm facing a problema with my job,

I'm trying to read records from database and write in a txt file. The database contains 1.800.000 records, with 149 columns, the problem is that the select is in the jobConfig.xml, in the bean 'mysqlItemReader', but, i think the select try to load all records in the JVM memory and then i got out of memory, using randtb.cliente limit 200000 it runs ok, but more than 500k of records i got out of memory, how avoid this error? Thanks!

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 

  http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="Context.xml" />
<bean id="tutorial" class="extractor.main.Tutorial" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="extractor.main.CustomItemProcessor" />

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="mysqlItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="50">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="mysqlItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="select * from randtb.cliente"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="extractor.main.TutorialRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="flatFileItemWriter" class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:target/outputfiles/employee_output.txt" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
            class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Use pagination?

Comment: Pagination is not effective (well it is, but there are even better ways). You want to set the fetch size to a suitable size so the driver won't try to load all the rows into memory at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, MySql will return everything in the `ResultSet` which is causing your OOM exception.  In order for it not to do that, you need to set the `JdbcCursorItemReader#setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`.  This will tell Spring Batch to set that value on the `PreparedStatement` as well as setting `PreparedStatement#setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD)`.  This will tell MySql to stream the data, thereby not blowing your stack.

So for your specific example, you need to change your `ItemReader` configuration to be:

```
<bean id="mysqlItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="select * from randtb.cliente"/>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).MIN_VALUE}"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="extractor.main.TutorialRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can read more about how this works in MySql in their documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html (see the ResultSet section).

Comment: I've been a bit confused about this (I've seen it quite often recently). If my understanding is correct, setting the fetch size with MySQL will work just fine when set to let's say `1000`, but the particular combo (forward cursor, fetch size min value) will result in a different binary protocol being used and rows are returned one by one and not in batches like with fetch size normally?

Comment: Per the MySql documentation, in order for the fetch size attribute to work the way you are describing, you need to set a value on the connection (`useCursorFetch=true`).  That's a much more complex way of managing it so Spring Batch doesn't expose that method.  If you want to fetch in blocks like that, using the `JdbcPagingItemReader` is a better alternative.

Comment: Ah right, I had read that previously. Specialties of MySQL / Connector/J I suppose.

Comment: I got com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic$OperationNotSupportedException: Operation not supported for streaming result sets, butt i add this 

<property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
And it looks like it worked

Comment: According to documentation: "There are some caveats with this approach. You must read all of the rows in the result set (or close it) before you can issue any other queries on the connection, or an exception will be thrown."

But, i can create another connection and do another queries, right?

Comment: @MichaelMinella -  Does this works in case of Postgressql?

Answer (score 0):

Without verifyCursorPosition i got the `om.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic$OperationNotSupportedException: Operation not supported for streaming result sets`

But, adding it, looks like it worked

```
<bean id="mysqlItemReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="sql" value="select * from randtb.cliente"/>
<property name="fetchSize" value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).MIN_VALUE}"/>
<property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="extractor.main.TutorialRowMapper"/>
</property>
```