# Spring Batch - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring batch to extract a large volume of data from database to CSV file.

The program runs fine in a test environment with a reduced data volume, but when I attempt to run the batch in production with a larger data volume (6 million records), the program drags on due to insufficient memory. By changing the affected RAM from 4 GB to 7 GB the program ends in a few minutes. But I don't want to run after RAM, especially since the volume of data is increasing significantly. Can you help me set up a configuration to optimize memory usage and accomplish batch processing in a reasonable time.
Thank you in advance for your help.

job.xml

```
<beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <import resource="launch-context.xml" />

  <!-- increment automatique de l'id du job -->
  <bean id="idIncrementer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

  <!-- Listener -->
  <bean id="extractMensJobExecutionListener" class="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.job.ExtractMensJobExecutionListener" />
<!--  <bean id="assureWriterListener" class="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.job.AssureWriterListener"/>-->

  <!--Reader-->
  <bean id="assureReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
        scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
      <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.PostgresPagingQueryProvider">
        <property name="selectClause" value="${query.sql.select.clause}" />
        <property name="fromClause" value="${query.sql.from.clause}" />
        <property name="whereClause" value="${query.sql.where.clause}"/>
        <property name="groupClause" value="${query.sql.group.by.clause}"/>
        <property name="sortKeys">
          <map>
            <entry key="${query.sql.sort.key.column}" value="${query.sql.sort.key.type}"/>
          </map>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="10000" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
      <bean class="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.reader.AssureMapper" />
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!--beans helper s for writer-->
  <bean id="fastDateFormat" class="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.datetime.FastDateFormat"
        factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyyMMdd" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="currentDate" factory-bean="fastDateFormat"
        factory-method="format">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="java.util.Date" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <!--Writer-->
  <bean id="assureWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
  scope = "step">
    <property name="resource" ref = "outputResource"/>
    <property name="headerCallback" ref="assureHeaderCallback"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
      <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
        <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
        <property name="fieldExtractor">
          <bean class="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.writer.AssureFieldExtractor" />
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="outputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" >
    <constructor-arg value = "./ficout/#{currentDate}_Extraction_Comptes_PCI.csv"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="assureHeaderCallback" class="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.writer.AssureHeaderCallback" />

  <!-- job -->

  <b:job id="extractionMensJob" incrementer="idIncrementer">
    <b:listeners>
      <b:listener ref="extractMensJobExecutionListener" />
    </b:listeners>
    <b:step id="readWrite">
      <b:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <b:chunk reader="assureReader" writer="assureWriter" commit-interval=10000 />

      </b:tasklet>
<!--
      <b:listeners>
        <b:listener ref="assureWriterListener" />
      </b:listeners>
-->
    </b:step>
  </b:job>
</beans>
```

lauch-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="cnav.gipur.pci.batch.model"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>cnav.gipur.pci.batch.model.Assure</value>
        <value>cnav.gipur.pci.batch.model.Affiliation</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>


  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" >
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="repositoryTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>


  <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean"
        p:transactionManager-ref="repositoryTransactionManager" />

  <bean id="jobOperator"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator"
        p:jobLauncher-ref="simpleJobLauncher" p:jobExplorer-ref="jobExplorer"
        p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" p:jobRegistry-ref="jobRegistry" />

  <bean id="jobExplorer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

  <bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="simpleJobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:batch-default.properties"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring batch version:**
4.4.2

**below are some implementation details:**

The Reader reads the data in the database. No processing in the processor because all the processing is done via the SQL query. The writter exports the result to the CSV file

Comment: Probably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588433/spring-batch-out-of-memory-after-huge-select-in-a-job which is related to Mysql, but I see you are using Postgres. There are a few conditions that should be met to achieve streaming in postgres: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/query.html#query-with-cursor. Make sure you are satisfying those conditions (use postgres 7.4+, use protocol v3+, etc).